# Edit HTML .tmLanguage file in Sublime Text 2 to handle inline Handlebars templates

Tags: regex, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext2, text-editor, handlebars.js

I have recently been incorporating [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/) into some new projects. I have been using inline Handlebars templates, as well as regular inline javascript.

The problem is that Sublime Text 2 treats inline Handlebars templates as if they were JS, which means the syntax coloring is completely wrong.

One [proposed solution](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2815) I've come across is to simply comment out the inline Javascript portion of Sublime Text's **[HTML.tmLanguage](http://pastebin.com/irTLDzKC)** file, from lines 284 to 379.

While this does result in proper coloring of Handlebars templates, it also hoses the syntax coloring for inline Javascript.

Is there a way to get the best of both worlds here? Maybe a way to edit the following line from HTML.tmLanguage to make it NOT apply to any script tag with `type="text/x-handlebars-template"` ?

```
<string>(?:^\s+)?(&lt;)((?i:script))\b(?![^&gt;]*/&gt;)</string>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User Iamntz was able to [answer my question](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2815#p46062) on the sublimetext forum.

The winning regex is:

```
<string>(?:^\s+)?(&lt;)((?i:script))\b(?!([^&gt;]*text/x-handlebars-template[^&gt;]*|[^&gt;]*/>))</string>
```

Comment: Great solution! What file exactly is this changed in? Is there a way to do this in a /Packages/User/ file so that it won't get reset with a Sublime upgrade?